# Upgrade Mac OS from El Capitan to Sierra

Tags: macos

How can I find the build date of a serial number like W89072N87WY to check if an upgrade from El Capitan 10.11.6 is possible.

What’s the process to check for Sierra?

Answer (score 2):

Apple has machine friendly names for Sierra  here.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208202

Since you didn’t show that, use [Everymac's Ultimate Mac Lookup](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=W89072N87WY&g-recaptcha-response=03AHaCkAZXy9MYjEOHzSsQxmRQ776mvLUGHzbzKxPDJw-w0M0H7eJHuRd-OvaHoKG9AESLwabyeK9wXOxDbN-azTXWVp693nV1mdm_Ki6-jUArasD6Ztn0ny_hoTeOUoaRAyyNG9owkZKvvnGXSLSyXIYK0rv9vDuuSPxkbjOZkobqHmlH26V4n1KOvIO6TePAFNEpjiUOvnH3XM32oc8yNPM4pfJMeW_Gd3f3Sb-vk757zx4aou8OL7hMjhmQuzQ_q-nBLu79v_RpRpuruq8rSxrWCFc8_sWXhBTjCUBGEf83gEWZsayJeLDZ4SxF8QF68732lcFJUIvDqES2z733GdqcTkbi21SRIjBx3I4aspLyC131PoaoCM8_ESYDNkVqGNxc6Foqe0SU)

This is a [MacBook "Core 2 Duo" 2.0 13" (Unibody)](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.0-aluminum-13-late-2008-unibody-specs.html), maximum macOS 10.11.x - so, no, it's been upgraded as far as it will go.